# Facebook javascript: how to get the list of actions that user did with the app

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am creating an app that helps a user post articles to their timeline if they want.
I also want to help them to easily remove a past action directly on my website.

I am looking for a solution using javascript.
I want to create a list of the last 10 actions (ID, Title) the User did using my app with the current Facebook logged/authorized user id, and my app ID.

There are no details of list action in the help here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/

Comment: Woop i been with stackoverflow for long but i didnt know that We need user V mark to gain reputation. before i have tried user voting up and down but the system never let me do it, so from now i know what that mark is for.. thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve all actions that were published by the current user](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13291676/how-to-retrieve-all-actions-that-were-published-by-the-current-user)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of actions from the same endpoint you are publishing them against – just using, as usual, GET instead of POST:

`/userid/{namespace}:{action-type-name}`